# Change AG grid previous cellStyle dynamically based on condition of other nodes or row value

Tags: angular5, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I can able to change current cellStyle based on some condition of current node. But I have to change the immediate previous cellStyle based on some condition in current node.

```
columnDefs = [
               { headerName: "TripStatus", field: "TripStatusCode",cellStyle: this.cellStyling},    
             ]
```

Call following method to change the style dynamically

```
cellStyling(params:any){  
       // This will change the current cell style only. But I need to change the style of immediate previous cell style. 
       if(params.node.TripStatusCode==='CO')   
       return {'background-color': 'red'};
  }
```

Comment: If you add a plunker, I will try to point you in the red direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [cellClassRules](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/#cell-class-rules%20cellClassRules)

```
cellClassRules = {
   'your-css-class': params => {
      if (params.colDef.field === "myCurrentField" &&
          params.data["previousField"] === "value") {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   },
   'your-other-css-class': params => {return false}
}
```

You can define as many class rules as you need, just separate by comma and the function should return true/false.